# Matlab change figure size to properly save to .png

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, display

I have a plot I get from matlab, with the x-axis ranging from 0 to 1864 values. I want to save this plot as a .png image without need to modify the original .fig file manually

My plot looks like this:

[image: My image]

As you can see, the last two numbers are overlapping. The reason is that when matlab displays my image, the popup window is too small. I already tried to change the axes ratio using `daspect`, but it does not work.
What I think could work is to use the function `truesize`, my problem is that when I try to use it, I receive the following error:

```
No images or texturemapped surfaces in the figure.
```

My code looks like this:

```
x = rand (1864,1);
F = bar (x);
xlim ([0 1864]);
set(gca, 'XTick', sort([1864, get(gca, 'XTick')]));
truesize(1,[100 100])
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix this problem in order to save the images preventing x labels overlapping?

Comment: It happens because you're trying to cram a label in where there isn't room. You need to either change the [`'Position'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_position) property of your figure window, the [`'XTickLabelRotation'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_xticklabelrotation) property of your axes, or both.

Comment: Is it important for you to show the last tick label `1864`?

Comment: Yes it is quite important. Of course I could insert it later but it I this would slow down my work a lot since I am making plenty of these images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try rotating your x labels using the following code:

```
x = rand (1864,1);
F = bar (x);
xlim ([0 1864]);
set(gca, 'XTick', sort([1864, get(gca, 'XTick')]));
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 90)
```

Note that you can change the degrees to rotate to other number besides 90 if you wanted.

It gives you a plot that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I actually did not want to rotate the numbers but it seems it is the most efficient way. Can I also take advantage of this moment to ask you how your bar graph seems much more smooth than mine? I mean, as you can see in your graph a lot of white area are distinguishable, differently from mine where blue homogenize entire areas

Comment: I hadn't noticed that before. I went back and re-ran the code in Matlab R2012b, the only other version I had installed on my computer and it made a plot similar to yours, without the witespace between bars. The main thing that I can think of is that Matlab has updated their bar function to use a higher resolution. What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: I am currently running Matlab 2015b, so I guess there must be something else, not just the version.

Comment: Could be something to do with the random number generator state. I'll look and see if I can change it.

Comment: Can you type in the command 'rng' in the command window and see what ans is?

Comment: I get as rng "Type: 'twister'; Seed: 0, State: [625x1 uit32]". I also tried to change the BarWidth and LineWidth but it does not seem to be the reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117424/discussion-between-user3716193-and-tommaso-sacco).